# Activating td button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have the following function, which is used to expand and collapse child `tr` rows from parent rows within a table, and also changes the text style of a `tr` to normal:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.parent').on('click', function(){
          $(this).next('.child').toggle();
          $(this).css('font-weight', 'normal');

          <<< ADD COMMAND TO TOGGLE BUTTON HERE >>>
     });
 });
```

I also have the following hidden button within each `tr`, which I want to submit when a `tr` is clicked:

```
<button type="submit" name="read-button" formmethod="POST" value="{{ message.message_id }}" style="display: none;"></button>
```

Which command should I include alongside the JavaScript function, in order to achieve this? I believe it will be one of the following (provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211351/9950593) answer), however I've only been using JS for a few days so I'm not sure how to include these in my code:

```
document.getElementById('read-button').submit();
changeAction('read-button','loginForm');
document.forms['read-button'].submit();
```

Sample html:

```
<form method=['POST']>
<table>
    <tr class="parent">
         <td>
             <button type="submit" name="read-button" formmethod="POST" value="{{ message.message_id }}" style="display: none;"></button>
             <a>Heres a cell</a>
         </td>
         <td>
             <a>
                Heres one more cell
             <a>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
         <td>
             <a>
                Some hidden info
             </a>
         </td>
         <td>
             <a>
                More hidden info
             </a>
         </td>
    </tr>
<table>
</form>
```

Comment: Laurie I notice you have a submit, but no form. Have you considered using AJAX to send the data back using Javascript?  If you are going to use a traditional form submit, you will need to be capturing data in inputs.

Comment: Hi Paul, I had the form element outside of my sample, please find it updated. I'm not sure AJAX would work as I'm using Python Flask for my backend. All I want is for when a user clicks a row, the ID of that row is sent to Flask so the SQL table in which the row belongs can be updated (without refreshing the page).

Comment: Ok, your form will natively handle the submit. But it will do a post back. i.e. a refresh of the page. The way to avoid that is AJAX, This could even be a blank POST to a url with param. e.g. `/myurl/mypage?tblID=123`

Comment: Thankyou, one more thing I have to learn now!

Comment: Take a look here. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ although you really dont need jQuery to do any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question of how to trigger a `button` within a `td` via clicking on the `tr`:

```
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find("button").click();
```

that can be improved by giving the button a class (incase you add additional buttons in future), eg:

```
<button class='readbutton' ..`
```

then

```
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find("button.readbutton").click();
```

---

In this scenario, it seems that you don't need a hidden button as you can call the functionality of the hidden button directly.

So rather than:

```
$("button").click(handleClick);
```

use

```
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
    .. other functionality ...
    handleClick();
```

as you're new to js, note the difference between `handleClick` and `handleClick()` - with `()` it calls the function, without it passes it as a function variable.

```
$("button").click(handleClick);
```

is the same as

```
$("button").click(function() { handleClick(); });
```

---

If you're trying to submit a form, then you would use `$(form).submit()` - but there's no form in the code as pointed out in the comments and an ajax call would seem more appropriate here than submitting a form.

---

Finally, consider using classes rather than setting the css directly as adding/removing classes it quite simple in jquery eg for your `tr` click event add:

```
$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again mate, very appreciated.